# ASP.NET MVC 3 not generating validation data attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I have a huge Form that I split in terms of Views (Partials) & ViewModels.

The main form view, contains calls to:

```
@Html.Partial("Educations", @Model)
```

The partial view, renders itself by looping over @Model, generating a Div row for each record (TextBox not TextBoxFor or any other Html helper).

What happens is that, no validation data attributes are being generated for the partial view.

One note though, once I load the main form view dynamically, I do the following:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.updateValidation = function () {
    var form = this.find("form")
        .removeData("validator")
        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    return this;
};
```

})(jQuery);

Also, the partial view contains a button to add more rows. When I add additional rows, those newly added ones are being validated as I inject manually the data validation.

The problem now is that, the rows that are rendered upon loading form are not having any data validation attribute, and hence even calling the above plugin to re-initialize unobtrusive validation, wont help or make any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a form context to your partial view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();               
}

...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

If the HTML helpers such as `Html.TextBoxFor` are not used inside a `Html.BeginForm` they will not emit the HTML5 data-* attributes. They only emit those attributes if there's a `FormContext` in scope.

Comment: In fact, the main form contains a single "Form", inside the "Form" I do a call to @Html.Partial("ViewName", @Model), the generation happens inside the partial view. In other words, the generated HTML is inside "Form", right?

Comment: This helped in my case as I've had a list of elements, each rendered in same partial view. After first view was rendered, all properties were marked as rendered (it's a private property) and so all following elements were skipped. Clearing the form context helped, although not sure what will be side effects in this or later versions.